# Freemarker -> Iterating over nested lists

Tags: list, macros, nested, freemarker

I am iterating over 2 lists in Freemarker:

```
<#list sectionData.rows as row>
    <#list row.macros as checkmacro>
        ${checkmacro.header.text1}
    </#list>
</#list>
```

But when it runs `${checkmacro.header.text1}` , it says that `checkmacro.header` is undefined.

In java class, `Header` is a class and `text1` is a field.

PS: I am able to print the fields correctly: `${checkmacro.defaultValue}` gives me the correct value.

Comment: I think we need to see the Java code that sets up your model.

Comment: Does the object representing checkmacro have a method called getHeader (with no arguments)?